# What's this book about a girls coming-of-age tale οn another planet?

Tags: story-identification

The story is a part of a series about a girl on another planet. The planet is very nature-orientated.

The plot seems to be that the girl breaks some kind of crystal ball meant to teach her lessons about life. All children, girls, are given this ball. She then has to learn the lessons herself and find the pieces of her crystal ball. The book was a couple into the series—I never looked for the first one. In the book, the girl went on a field trip to a forested planet, I think like a national park, and then has to face creatures of fear there with a classmate she hates. The cover was beautiful with a red-haired girl, flowers, and an aquamarine background.

Answer (score 5):

I've been looking for this book for 10 yrs since I read it when I was a kid and I think is is *[Zenda and the Gazing Ball](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0448432234)*.

[image: Book Cover]

> *I didn’t mean for things to happen this way. But they did. Now while everyone else moves forward, my entire life is on hold! Even worse, the magical gift that holds the key to my future is in jeopardy. I want to make everything right. But what if I can’t?*
>
> So begins the adventure of twelve-year-old Zenda from Azureblue, a magical green planet where the quest for spiritual enlightenment is as natural to living as breathing. Smart, gifted, and headstrong, yet also a sensitive dreamer, Zenda is the quintessential girl on the verge of adolescence: always changing, always questioning, and constantly seeking to make sense of her world and her place in it. Featuring a thoroughly modern yet timeless character, Zenda is the ultimate series for today’s sophisticated ’tween girl.
>
> The biggest day of Zenda’s life is finally here: In a few short hours she will be presented with her very own gazing ball. It is the gazing ball that will reveal her thirteen special “musings,” the lessons unique to Zenda that will guide her on her journey through life. Then, Zenda breaks her gazing ball and her thirteen musings vanish and scatter out into the atmosphere. It’s up to Zenda to find them; if not, she risks never fulfilling her potential—or her secret dreams.

Comment: Welcome to SFF.SE! Could you possibly add some details about the book's plot to this answer? Link-only answers tend to be discouraged here, since if the link dies the answer becomes almost useless (in this case, the answer would be just a title which people would then have to Google).